# Connect to EC2 instance programmatically?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to android development and AWS. I am trying to make a PDF convertor android app where user can upload a TEXT file to EC2 (in EBS volume), it is then processed by my EC2 instance and then stored in S3.

My primary task is to connect(and upload file) to EC2 instance from my Android program. How can I do it?

I know that using PUTTY and SSH we can upload files to EC2. How it can be done programmatically in my case?

Comment: I advise you to use HTTP uploads instead so that you don't have to deal with client and ISP firewalls that blocks other protocols.

Comment: Good design would be upload the file to S3 because its persistent storage. Retrieve and process the file and send the the output back to S3. That way you will have both raw and processed file. AWS SDK are available to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are writing this for an android app, connecting via SSH probably isn't the best way to go. You would have to put your key/password in the app, and it could likely be extracted.

The general way to solve something like this is to set up a REST API. You can write this in any language you feel comfortable with. The REST API would process the upload and do all the server side work.

Comment: Seems like a nice solution. Can you suggest a good tutorial to make REST API calls to EC2 ?it would be great help !

Comment: You will need to write an application that will run on EC2 instance. You can do this in just about any language/framework. REST is a paradigm that sets guidelines on how you would send requests to your ec2 instance. Something like this gives an overview to REST: http://rest.elkstein.org/